# How can I calculate the sum of Legacy Form Fields without werid scrolling?

Tags: vba, ms-word, scroll

I have a Word document with a table that contains the price of an item, the order amount and the item sum, where amount and item sum are Legacy Form Fields:

[image: price, amount, item sum]

There are other items available as options that you can chose via checkbox (also Legacy Form Fields):

[image: optional items]

## Code

Now I've created a function that calculates the item sum

```
Sub order_amount_Click()
    Dim amount As Integer
    Dim valueFromCell As String
    Dim list
    Dim value As Double

    amount = ActiveDocument.FormFields("order_amount").Result
    If amount > 0 Then
        valueFromCell = ThisDocument.Tables(1).Cell(5, 3).Range.Text
        list = Split(valueFromCell, " ")
        value = list(0)
        subsum = value * amount
        ActiveDocument.FormFields("order_amount_sum").Result = subsum
    Else
        ActiveDocument.FormFields("order_amount_sum").Result = 0
    End If

    CalculateSum
End Sub
```

and another function that calculates the item sum for additional items (if the checkbox is activated) multiplied by the order amount:

```
Sub optional_item_Click()
    Dim checkbox As Integer
    Dim valueFromCell As String
    Dim list
    Dim value As Double
    Dim amount As Integer
    Dim subsum As Double

    checkbox = ActiveDocument.FormFields("optional_item1").Result
    amount = ActiveDocument.FormFields("order_amount").Result

    If checkbox = 1 And amount > 0 Then
        valueFromCell = ThisDocument.Tables(1).Cell(7, 3).Range.Text
        list = Split(valueFromCell, " ")
        value = list(0)
        subsum = value * amount
        ActiveDocument.FormFields("optional_item1_sum").Result = subsum
    Else
        ActiveDocument.FormFields("optional_item1_sum").Result = 0
    End If

    CalculateSum
End Sub
```

(There are as many `Click()` functions as there are `optional_item` fields, 17 in sum - I haven't generalized the function yet.)

The last line within both `Sub`s is a function call, that calculates the net sum, the VAT and the final total sum

[image: net, VAT and total sum]

```
Function CalculateSum()
    Dim net As Double
    Dim vat As Double
    Dim total_sum As Double

    net = CDbl(ActiveDocument.FormFields("order_amount_sum").Result) + CDbl(ActiveDocument.FormFields("optional_item1_sum").Result) + CDbl(ActiveDocument.FormFields("optional_item2_sum").Result) + CDbl(ActiveDocument.FormFields("optional_item3_sum").Result) + CDbl(ActiveDocument.FormFields("optional_item4_sum").Result) + CDbl(ActiveDocument.FormFields("optional_item5_sum").Result) + CDbl(ActiveDocument.FormFields("optional_item6_sum").Result) + CDbl(ActiveDocument.FormFields("optional_item7_sum").Result) + CDbl(ActiveDocument.FormFields("optional_item8_sum").Result) + CDbl(ActiveDocument.FormFields("optional_item9_sum").Result)

    ' Cannot compile when line too long, so splitting into two statements
    net = net + CDbl(ActiveDocument.FormFields("optional_item10_sum").Result) + CDbl(ActiveDocument.FormFields("optional_item11_sum").Result) + CDbl(ActiveDocument.FormFields("optional_item12_sum").Result) + CDbl(ActiveDocument.FormFields("optional_item13_sum").Result) + CDbl(ActiveDocument.FormFields("optional_item14_sum").Result) + CDbl(ActiveDocument.FormFields("optional_item15_sum").Result) + CDbl(ActiveDocument.FormFields("optional_item16_sum").Result) + CDbl(ActiveDocument.FormFields("optional_item17_sum").Result)
    'MsgBox "net " & net
    ActiveDocument.FormFields("net_sum").Result = net

    vat = net * 0.19
    'MsgBox "vat " & vat
    ActiveDocument.FormFields("vat_sum").Result = vat

    total_sum = net + vat
    'MsgBox "total " & total_sum
    ActiveDocument.FormFields("total_sum").Result = total_sum
End Function
```

## Problem

The code itself works fine, all elements are calculated correctly. But there are two major problems that make the whole document almost unusable (all actions for users are restricted to enter their name on top of the document, chose the amount and de-/activate the checkboxes; sum fields aren't accessible):

1. When I perform an action (e.g. enter an amount) the `CalculateSum()` function visibly loops over all `sum` fields (spanned over three pages) and weirdly scrolls on the document along the `sum` fields.
2. When I click on a checkbox on the 2nd or 3rd page, the document scrolls up to the first page to the place where I can enter the amount of pieces I want to order.

Now how can I supress all that looping over the `sum` fields and weirdly scrolling around? And how can I prevent the document from scrolling up to the 1st page?

Any help appreciated! (I'm also thankful for side comments on my code, as I'm new to VBA.)

## Update #1

I've added a [screencast showing the error](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/859390/weird-scrolling.mp4).

## Update #2

The basic problem seems to be that the macro is scrolling to the position I am referring to in my script, e.g. if I'm using

```
ActiveDocument.FormFields("total_sum").Result = total_sum
```

it's scrolling to the `total_sum` field.

Comment: have you tried `application.screenupdating = false` and `DoEvents` ?

Comment: I haven't heard about any of those, but will have a look. Thanks for advising!

Comment: @vba4all The `application.screenupdating = false` already surpresses the document from looping over each `sum` field - but still scrolls down.

Where would I place the `DoEvents`?

Comment: Doesn't really help, now -when changing the amount- it weirdly scrolls around and stops between page 2 and 3. If I'm changing checkboxes it scrolls around and -at least- gets back to checkbox position.

Comment: You would have to give instructions how to reproduce this problem...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64687/discussion-between-gottlieb-notschnabel-and-vba4all).

Comment: @vba4all Could you reproduce the problem?

Comment: no. getting a type mismatch right away and I don't have time at the moment to play it.

Comment: I see. However, thanks for your help so far!

Comment: just add a link to your question so others can download

Comment: Some observations (a) this field type is generally now known in English as "Legacy Form Fields". "Content Controls" are the newerthings. (b) you may not need to use Form Fields to insert read-only information. Ssometimes you can use { = } fields and rely on the "Calculate on Exit" feature. I don't know if that would solve your scrolling problem. (c) You cannot reference the Checkbox field value in the "field language", but you may be able to use an Exit macro to (say) set the value of a DOoument Variable which you could then use in an { = } field via { DOCVARIABLE thevariablename }

Comment: @bibadia Thanks a lot for your help! About (a): thanks for the hint, I modified my question accordingly; about (b) I came from that approach but switched to VBA because I couldn't access the checkboxes' values; about (c) can you provide an example how this would look like?

Comment: @Gottlieb too complex for a comment, so I've posted as an Answer.

Comment: @vba4all I think the type mismatch will be due to local settings for the currency.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suppress unwanted jumping/scrolling on Word 2013 VBA macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889709/suppress-unwanted-jumping-scrolling-on-word-2013-vba-macro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [AdamsTips found out elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26891768/1828051), replacing this

```
ActiveDocument.FormFields("myField").Result
```

by this

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("myField").Range.Fields(1).Result
```

allows accessing the field without focusing it.

Answer (score 1):

Too difficult for a comment...

For (b) you have to use VBA - you can't use the trick I suggested elsewhere with the FormFields checkboxes, only with the Content Control ones.

For (c), something like this (not tested)

Make sure the On Exit macro is set for optional_item1 and the Calculate on Exit is also set. I don't think you need an On Entry macro as well.

```
Sub optional_item1_Click() 
  Call cb_Click("optional_item1") 
End Sub 

Sub cb_Click(ffname As String)
  ActiveDocument.Variables(ffname) = abs(int(ActiveDocument.FormFields(ffname).Checkbox.Value))
End Sub
```

In your Summa column, next to the checkbox, something like

```
{ ={ DOCVARAIABLE optional_item1 }*X2 }
```

where X2 is the cell that contains the 3,00 Euro value and all the {  } are the special field code brace pairs that you can insert using ctrl-F9 on Windows Word.

*BUT*

Whether Word will correctly interpret your Euro value correctly depends on the regional settings of the user using your form, (decimal separator, group (thousands) separator, currency symbol and location of the currency symbol may all change Word's behaviour. Even within the Eurozone I think some of those things can vary. So if the user does not need to modify the multiplier 3,00 Euros in the cell, it may be better to plug the value directly into the { = } field:

```
{ ={ DOCVARAIABLE optional_item1 }*3 }
```

You can also use \# numeric formats to give you the format you want when positive or 0. But again, Word's numeric formatting facility is not locale-independent).

Those locale dependencies are also sometimes a reason for doing more in VBA rather than field codes.

Comment: I will have a deeper look into it tomorrow. Thanks for now for your detailed answer!

Comment: This actually doesn't solve my weird scrolling problems. But I +1'ed it because it's a well researched and generally helpful answer. Thanks!