# How to properly access Legacy Form Field checkboxes in Word 2013 VBA?

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word

Coming from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889709/suppress-unwanted-jumping-scrolling-on-word-2013-vba-macro) I am trying to get and set the values for a Legacy Form Field checkbox (MS Word 2013) – without weirdly scrolling/jumping around on the document. For Text Fields this can be performed by

```
myField = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("myField").Range.Fields(1).Result ' get
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("myField").Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = myValue ' set
```

But this doesn't work for checkboxes. What commands can I take in order to access checkboxes accordingly and without weird jumping around?

Comment: related: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26889709/2140173), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26860611/2140173)

Comment: Yeah, definitely... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some testing on this, and it looks you can simply use the `CheckBox.Value` property to access the value of the checkbox without changing the focus in your document. Paste the following code into a regular module, and test the difference between these two ways of accessing the value of the text box.

```
Public Sub TestCheckboxAccess()

    Dim ctl As FormField

    For Each ctl In ActiveDocument.FormFields

        ' Loop through check boxes in current document
        If ctl.Type = wdFieldFormCheckBox Then

            ' This does not scroll the document
            Debug.Print ctl.CheckBox.Value

            ' This does scroll the document
            'Debug.Print ctl.Result

        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub
```

Note that on my system this code sample works even without turning off `ScreenUpdating`.

Give this a try, and see if it might solve the problem for you!

Comment: It doesn't help in my case. Try spreading checkbox over multiple pages, then it jumps around weirdly.

Comment: Did you try exactly as I described in the answer? Paste the code into a standard module, press F5 to run the macro. I have a multi-page document (the sample you sent me) and it doesn't scroll unless I uncomment the line that accesses the `Result` property.

Comment: You're completely right. I've modified my question accordingly (where I stated, that `.CheckBox.Value` is no good). Thanks!

Comment: Funny thing though: Now the value is `-1` instead of `1`. Anyhow, it's either `= 0` or `<> 0`, so I can handle that appropriately.

Comment: FYI, The value of -1 is also the same as `True`, so you can handle it as a Boolean value in your code. (`ctl.CheckBox.Value = True`)